# Write a list of Complex Numbers as Binary Data

Tags: python

I'm trying to output some data from a python script to a binary file.

If I have a list of floats I've been using this

```
out_file = open("filename", "wb")
float_array.array("f", [])
float_array.fromlist(mylist)
float_array.tofile(out_file)
out_file.close()
```

This seems to work fine, at least it's resulting in a file with the correct number of bytes.

How can I do the same thing but using a list of complex numbers?

Thanks

Comment: For complex numbers there is no standard binary representation (at least that I am aware of), so you will first have to decide how you want them represented.

Comment: I would be happy to have them as a list of doubles or floats.  It doesn't really matter as long as I can read them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a flattened list of floats out of your complex array like

```
flattend = [f for sublist in ((c.real, c.imag) for c in complex_list) for f in sublist]
```

and write this one to the file.

Comment: This is the route I went in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Don't invent your own serialization methods when Python offers so many good ones out of the box! I suggest you use pickle - it works with complex numbers as well (*):

```
>>> import pickle
>>> s = pickle.dumps([1+2j, 5-1j])
>>> pickle.loads(s)
[(1+2j), (5-1j)]
```

I'm using `dumps` for demonstration here, you can also use `dump` which writes to a binary file.

---

(*) From the doc of pickle:

> The following types can be pickled:
>
> - None, True, and False
> - integers, long integers, floating point numbers, **complex numbers**
> - normal and Unicode strings
> - tuples, lists, sets, and dictionaries containing only picklable
>     objects
> - functions defined at the top level of a module
> - built-in functions defined at the top level of a module
> - classes that are defined at the top level of a module
> - instances of such classes whose `__dict__` or `__setstate__()` is picklable (see section The pickle *
>     protocol for details)

Comment: Remember dumping when writing a pickle file to use binary mode ;)

Comment: Thanks,  I'm not sure if this is going to work.  It seems to be writing a lot more data than I expect.  I need to be able to read this data from C code so I need raw binary data.

Comment: @rvabdn: Python's cPickle is implemented in C, you could probably get it to work from C code. Maybe this is all too complex for your needs, but I'm just leaving it as a suggestion